# How to get only date from a DateTime value in Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

I am getting value `FromDate` from database and I am sending the data to my `View` using a `ViewModel`. In the `View`, I want to display the date (08/27/2018), but without the time value.

I am doing that in the following way:

```
@Model.FromDate
```

I have tried out the following different ways to get only the time value to show on the View:

```
@Model.FromDate.Value()

@Model.FromFate.GetValueOrDefault()
```

I even used a custom `DateTime` format. But I still get the complete `DateTime` value in the output. How can I get only the date and not the time in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using TextBoxFor you can use the following to show only the date -

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
```

Comment: If i want only dd/MM/yyyy ?

Answer (score 4):

You can format a `DateTime` using `ToString()`:

```
@Model.FromDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

These are the patterns:

```
0   MM/dd/yyyy  08/22/2006
1   dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  Tuesday, 22 August 2006
2   dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  HH:mm Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30
3   dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  hh:mm tt Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30 AM
4   dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  H:mm Tuesday, 22 August 2006 6:30
5   dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  h:mm tt Tuesday, 22 August 2006 6:30 AM
6   dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30:07
7   MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm    08/22/2006 06:30
8   MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt 08/22/2006 06:30 AM
9   MM/dd/yyyy H:mm 08/22/2006 6:30
10  MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt  08/22/2006 6:30 AM
10  MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt  08/22/2006 6:30 AM
10  MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt  08/22/2006 6:30 AM
11  MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss 08/22/2006 06:30:07
12  MMMM dd August 22
13  MMMM dd August 22
14  yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK  2006-08-22T06:30:07.7199222-04:00
15  yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK  2006-08-22T06:30:07.7199222-04:00
16  ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' Tue, 22 Aug 2006 06:30:07 GMT
17  ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' Tue, 22 Aug 2006 06:30:07 GMT
18  yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss   2006-08-22T06:30:07
19  HH:mm   06:30
20  hh:mm tt    06:30 AM
21  H:mm    6:30
22  h:mm tt 6:30 AM
23  HH:mm:ss    06:30:07
24  yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'  2006-08-22 06:30:07Z
25  dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30:07
26  yyyy MMMM   2006 August
27  yyyy MMMM   2006 August
```

All the patterns are available at
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use String.Format for this. For example:

```
@String.Format({"0:dd/MM/yyyy"}, @Model.FromDate);
```

Hope to help, my friend!